# Cross Sell Upsell Product Page extension

Tags: magento2, cross-sells, upselling

I have spent last 3 days looking for an extension which will allow me to show both cross sell and upsell on the product page - magento 2.4.3

I dont want automatic or AI based extension - just a simple extension to show the cross sell and upsell added in the product catalog during import to show on the product page.

I also dont want any extension that you have to manually add each product you want to show in cross sell upsell manually via admin as we have 1000's of products and most products have cross sell and upsell products

Ideally we want to show these in a slider

we have found and installed weltpixel RESPONSIVE BANNER SLIDER & OWL CAROUSEL extension but this only allows for upsell to show on product page not cross sell -
if anyone can guide on how to manipulate this extension to show cross sells too - that would be grear aswell

Would appreciate if someone can help asap with this

Thank You

Comment: Cross-sell product depends on the cart & its display on the cart page if you want to display it on a product page then you need to do a custom code.